# jQuery Function is calling repeatedly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using following code, to hide and display form

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form_before_launch").click(function(){
        $(this).animate({height:"300px" ,width:"400px"});
        $(this).children("p").animate({fontSize:"35px"});
        $("#form").delay(500).fadeIn();
    })

    $("#close").click(function(){
        $(this).animate({height:"0px" ,width:"0px"});
    })
});
```

Following code is working for `form_before_launch`, but once I click div element with 'close' id, `#close` function is called and after that `#form_before_launch` is called again.

Comment: Is the close element inside the form_before_launch element?

Comment: @Taplar : yes its in same element

Comment: yeah, that's how click events work

Answer (score -1):

If the element is inside the `form_before_launch` the event is of course propagating to both handlers.

```
$("#close").click(function(){
    $(this).animate({height:"0px" ,width:"0px"});
    return false;
})
```

Comment: @Orpheus eh, i think you are incorrect. at least for jQuery bound events. finding docs.

Comment: @Orpheus returning false does both preventDefault and stopPropagation.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/on/ *"Returning false from an event handler will automatically call `event.stopPropagation()` and `event.preventDefault()`."*

Comment: Was running off a rough bit of old information. My bad.

Probably useful to still deliberately invoke it on the event argument anyways to be completely unambiguous.

Answer (score -2):

Try passing in 'e' to the close click event and then call `e.stopPropagation()` so the event doesn't bubble up to be processed by the encapsulating form_before_launch element.